# .click, .live, .on... Not firing for my code?

Tags: jquery, live

I am at a loss for why this is not working? I use click, live, on all the time and it just works but not here... Any idea why?

What is not working in the p.tableItem.live

the rendered row would look like this

```
<tr>
    <td>
<p id="spEmailAddress_2_0" class="tableItem" alt="EmailAddress">charlie.nguyen@exacttarget.com</p></td><td><p id="spUserID_2_1"  class="tableItem" alt="Number">10442135</p></td><td><p id="spSubscriberKey_2_2" class="tableItem" alt="Text">charlie.nguyen@exacttarget.com</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the script that is not running

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.post(wsUrl, { Method: "GetDEs"}).done(function(data){
            data = CreateObjectFromOutput(data);
            $("#DEContainer").html(BuildDEDDL(data));

            $("#ddlDE").change(function(){
                $.post(wsUrl, { Method: "GetFieldsAndRows", Input: JSON.stringify({ DEName: $(this).val()})}).done(function(data){
                    data = CreateObjectFromOutput(data);
                    $("#FieldContainer").html(BuildFiledTable(data));
                    $(".Date").datepicker();
                });
            });
        });

        $("p.tableItem").live("click", function(event){
            alert($(this).text());
        });

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Wrapper">
        <div id="DEContainer"></div>
        <div id="FieldContainer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/48zRG/ make sure it is not a problem with something else breaking the rest of the javascript.

Comment: errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this ?

```
$("p.tableItem").click(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

or

```
 $("p.tableItem").bind('click', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Neither of those would work as the element doesn't exist yet when that code runs.

Comment: I am doing this all dynamically so the live event handles that. I did try click but it is not working either, I think the first comment is right, must be something else breaking it

Answer (score 0):

A table row has to be in a `table` element, not in a `div` element. Change it to a table:

```
<table id="FieldContainer"></table>
```